# Athena: Calculating Age from String "birth_dt" Column

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am working with a dataset that has a column titled "birth_dt" from which I am trying to calculate the age of the member as of 18 months ago from.

This is what "select distinct(birth_dt) from table.DB limit 9;" shows the column to look like:

```
birth_dt
-----------------------
1990-08-15 00:00:00.000
1986-05-30 00:00:00.000
1981-03-03 00:00:00.000
1970-05-11 00:00:00.000
1963-01-20 00:00:00.000
1985-01-26 00:00:00.000
1983-01-03 00:00:00.000
2021-01-03 00:00:00.000
1995-11-14 00:00:00.000
```

In Athena, this column shows as being a "string".

So far, what I have tried is:

```
select DATE_DIFF('year', birth_dt, (current_timestamp - interval '18' month)) as age from table.DB limit 10;
```

which kept giving me an error saying:

> "SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (varchar(4), varchar, timestamp with time zone) for function date_diff. Expected: date_diff(varchar(x), time, time) , date_diff(varchar(x), time with time zone, time with time zone) , date_diff(varchar(x), timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) , date_diff(varchar(x), date, date) , date_diff(varchar(x), timestamp, timestamp)"

So then I tried to just focus on getting that "birth_dt" column to change to a valid date to no avail with the following:

```
select date_parse(birth_dt, '%YYYY-%MM-%dd') as age from table.DB limit 10;

select cast(from_iso8601_timestamp("birth_dt.1") AS date) as age from table.DB limit 10;

SELECT date_parse(birth_dt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%+00:00') as date_column,
current_timestamp as Todays_Date,
date_diff('day',current_timestamp,date_parse(birth_dt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%+00:00')) as difference
FROM table.DB limit 10;
```

These queries end up giving me errors that say either:

> "INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "1990-08-15 00:00:00.000" is malformed at "-08-15 00:00:00.000""

or

> "INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "1990-08-15 00:00:00.000" is malformed at "00:00:00.000""

What I want to eventually have for my examples above is:

```
Age
---
31
35
40
51
58
36
38
1
25
```

Please help! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing valid format is crucial here. Some attempts where really close, try the following:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(birth_dt) AS (
    values ('1983-01-03 00:00:00.000'),
        ('2021-01-03 00:00:00.000')
)

-- query
select date_diff(
        'year',
        date_parse(birth_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f'),
        current_timestamp - interval '18' month)
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 41 |
| 3 |

Check the [MySQL Date Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) docs for all supported format specifiers and what they mean.

Comment: you are a lifesaver!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much for your prompt response. I have been stuck on this for days. Thank you so much!!!